# Mid 1970s YA SF book with a time-travelling boy who goes to the future and returns alone

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, young-adult

Read in 1975 or so. Included a boy who ended up in the far future; he falls in love, and has adventures. The future is deadly for some reason and he has to return alone at the end, with a sad goodbye scene with his love. Not *The Transall Saga* or *Slaughterhouse-Five* (definitely YA, and not as dark as *Transall*).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it definitely 1975? I'm wondering about Rocco by Sherryl Jordan, but it was published in 1990.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking **The future took us** by David Severn - originally published 1958

Two English schoolboys are transported to the future by the scientists of the time (it was a near miss, they were actually trying to grab their mathematical genius headmaster)

They have various adventures in a brutal post apocalypse world and finally get a chance to go back to their own time.

However one has fallen in love with a future girl so his friend returns alone

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21079401-the-future-took-us

This **might** be the same [YA novel about boys travelling to post-apocalypse future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179999/ya-novel-about-boys-travelling-to-post-apocalypse-future/180000#180000)